# How can I customize self.ordering of ListVIew

Tags: python, django

I have `ListMyView` which has override `ListView`, it

It has the get_ordering function. I can set the ordering key as `sort_by`

```
class ListMyView(ListView):
    model = TestUserGroup
    def get_ordering(self):
        return self.request.GET.get("sort_by", self.ordering)
```

in model

```
class TestUserGroup(BaseModel):
    name = m.CharField()
    test_users = m.ManyToManyField(TestUser)
    def get_current_users(self):
       return self.test_users.all()
```

In this case I can use key `name` as `sort_by`, however when using `get_current_users` as `sort_by`

show this error.

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'get_current_users' into field. Choices are: created_at, created_by, name, id
```

Is there any way to use `get_current_users()` as sorting key?

Comment: the sorting is done in the db, so you can only use db columns as ordering values. not sure what you're trying to achieve by ordering against a queryset of users, but suitable ordering values are going to be only what you could specify in an `order_by` clause https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#order-by

Comment: @Anentropic I wonder whether it's possible to pass SQL expressions as well, either directly or via the use of a db view.

Comment: But you seem to order by a *collection* of `User`s, how is that supposed to work, even if we can transform this to SQL?